# How much horsepower to expect from a cold air intake in Dodge Ram

Tags: dodge, performance, truck, air-intake

It's a 1999 Dodge Ram 1500 4x4, Laramie SLT, automatic transmission, 5.9l magnum engine, and crew cab (222k mi).

[image]

I have a friend who could put a cold air intake on it, with a new hood. But I have a few questions.

1. Would there be a substantial enough of a horsepower boost to be noticeable?
2. Would the truck perform in the rain as well as before?
3. Is it safe to put this kind of performance part on an old engine with high mileage?

I would like to be sure it's worth it before buying any parts.

Comment: Are you looking to solve a current issue or are you just trying to get more power than stock out of it?

Comment: There are no issues with the stock intake yet, @DucatiKiller. I'd be looking for power/performance boost

Comment: IMO, you would not get that much of a gain out of it.  A bit, but I don't think you would get anything you could really notice.  I'm interested to see what the community says about this.

Comment: Not that much for the money to be invested. You should not expect anything more than 5HP. That is barely noticeable on such a heavy truck.

Comment: It's rated 245 hp

Comment: 5.9litre and only 245hp? there's a looots to be gained here, but i wouldn't look for ram air intakes. You only get a slight boost, and only at higher speeds. At lower speeds, the inertia of the air is too little to give a serious gain. I would recommend to get a K&N air filter first. It's the easiest and safest upgrade i can think of, and it doesn't cost much. Next you could look at the spark advance, the air fuel ratio, the manifold etc... But that demands for more time and money investment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Would there be a substantial enough of a horsepower boost to be noticeable?

The *most* you could see from such a modification is 15hp. This would not be enough for the seat dyno to register, unless there are plenty of hemorrhoids to detect it. More then likely you'd see a measly 5-10hp, and then only at the higher RPM levels would this be apparent. You would only be able to see the increase via a chassis dyno.

> Would the truck perform in the rain as well as before?

Depending on the modifications made (I'm unsure of the CAI you are planning to use) your truck won't have any issues using the CAI, nor will it have any issues in the rain. Even CAI's that utilize an exterior intake (as you've suggested in your question) usually have a drain the bottom which allows for any water which may enter to leave as well. You'd have to drown the entire truck to have an issue.

> Is it safe to put this kind of performance part on an old engine with high mileage?

It won't hurt anything ... but really, it won't help anything either. The engine will only use the air it can take in ... no more, no less. Allowing it to breath a little better won't hurt anything.

If you are getting these modifications for free, then no big deal ... put them on. If, on the other hand it might cost you money, I'd suggest you pass. It's not a good return on investment for your truck.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the 5-10 hp increase assumes the rest of the vehicle is in working order. If there are other things wrong with the vehicle, those should be addressed first. In some cases, fixing existing issues would actually give a greater hp increase than a CAI!

Answer (score 2):

Removing the acoustically engineered OEM intake and replacing it with a bit of pipe and cone filter is likely to result in a *decrease* in bhp. Most of the independent before and after tests done on non-turbo vehicles find that reduces performance.